# Opening a database made in SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a database built in SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition but am unable to open it in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. It says the version of my SQL Server is too old.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest Service Pack for your sql server, or if you want to send the database back, install the same Service Pack as the Developer Edition is using.

Comment: here is some other information about my question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/14161241-c22b-4d47-a589-15efa3c69b0f/